# POS Tagging arabic text using nltk in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, arabic, pos-tagger

I'm trying to `POS tagging` an `arabic` text with `NLTK` using `Python 3.6`, I found this program:

```
import nltk

text = """ و نشر العدل من خلال قضاء مستقل ."""

sentence = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(text)

# tokens = [nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(s) for s in sentence]
tokens = [nltk.tokenize.wordpunct_tokenize(s) for s in sentence]

# Here pos tagging isn't right :'(
PosTokens = [nltk.pos_tag(e) for e in tokens]

chunks = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(PosTokens)

for tree in chunks:
    print(tree)
```

**Result :**

```
(S
  و/JJ
  (ORGANIZATION نشر/NNP)
  العدل/NNP
  من/NNP
  خلال/NNP
  قضاء/NNP
  مستقل/NNP
  ./.)
```

This is a bad result, for example:
Although 'نشر' is verb,it's giving me a noun 'NNP'.

***The right result is :***

```
  (S (CC و)
    (VP (VBD نشر)
      (NP (DTNN العدل))
      (PP (IN من)
        (NP (NN خلال)
          (NP (NN قضاء) (JJ مستقل)))))
    (PUNC .))
```

Comment: It is likely that the NLTK POS tagger doesn't have enough training data for arabic. I would encourage you to use the Stanford POS tagger found here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml

Comment: @NickChapman Can I work with it using Python ?

Comment: Yeah you can use NLTK to access it, but you'll need to download the models from the Stanford website.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I hope it'll work